# sed and capturing groups in Makefile

Tags: linux, bash, sed, makefile

I'm trying to get the version of the last installed kernel:

```
all:
    echo /lib/modules/$(rpm -q kernel | tail -n 1 | sed -e's/kernel-\(.*\.x86_64\)/\1/')
```

I get the following error:

```
$ make all
echo /lib/modules//\1/')
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [Makefile:17: all] Error 1
```

But directly in bash:

```
$ echo $(rpm -q kernel | tail -n 1 | sed -e's/kernel-\(.*\.x86_64\)/\1/')
4.18.0-315.el8.x86_64
```

and

```
$ rpm -q kernel | tail -n 1 | sed -e's/kernel-\(.*\.x86_64\)/\1/'
4.18.0-315.el8.x86_64
```

- Why? It seems the `\)` is a problem when used in Makefile.

Comment: Try `$$(rpm...)`. Make expands the `$` before passing your command to the shell. So it replaces `$(rpm -q kernel | tail -n 1 | sed -e's/kernel-\(.*\.x86_64\)` by the value of a make variable named `rpm -q kernel | tail -n 1 ...`, that is, the null string, leaving just `echo /lib/modules//\1/')` which is incorrect.

Comment: I see, I don't use Makefile very often... that worked! Thanks! Please answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Always double the `$` signs in recipes if they must be passed to the shell. This means that if, for any reason, you want to pass `$$` to the shell you'll need to write `$$$$` in your make recipe. The old-fashioned back-ticks are sometimes used to avoid this with shell command expansion.

Comment: I prefer not adding an answer. At least not before I searched for a similar Q&A. It is very likely a duplicate.

Comment: Understood, should I delete my question?

Comment: I don't know what is the recommended practice in this case. Up to you, I guess.

Comment: I let it so that I can come back later. The question is closed anyway. Thanks again!